# Docker building docker images: User Permission/Host Questions

Tags: docker

I just spun up a fresh Ubuntu instance, and I have installed Docker

`docker --version` reports: Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d

I then ran two commands to setup a CI/CD pipeline:

1. `docker run -d -t -p 8153:8153 gocd/gocd-server`
2. For the agent, I am starting it as follows:

`docker run -d --privileged=true -ti -e GO_SERVER=<my_server_ip_address> -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/bin/docker gocd/gocd-agent`

Both containers are up and running as expected. `docker ps` reports the following:

```
25a7686b8653        gocd/gocd-server             "/sbin/my_init"        6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:8153->8153/tcp, 8154/tcp           
ec1ede694844        gocd/gocd-agent              "/sbin/my_init"        5 second                s ago       Up 5 seconds
```

When I access the `gocd-agent`, using the following command:

`sudo docker exec -i -t ec1ede694844 bash`

I am brought into the agent. Once inside, I can use commands like `docker images` without any issues.

The `go-agent` requires us to use a `go` user, so using the same terminal/container bash above, I type: `su go`

This brings me into the container as the `go` user (`go@ec1ede694844`).

When I try to use a command like `docker images` or `docker ps`, I get the following error message:

`Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?`

The only command that works is the standard `docker` command, which gives me the list of possible docker commands that I can use. However, none of these commands work while using the `go` user.

Is there any way to pass permissions from the container down into a user account?

Or, is there any way for me to reset the `docker.sock` so that it will allow my `go` user to run commands like `docker images`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Didn't try these docker images, but when you connect agent to gocd server, why not use `--link` option? The go cd server IP may keep changing.

Comment: This is a permissions error accessing a unix socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`). It has nothing to do with addresses.

Answer (score 1):

This error...

```
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: 
permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Means that `docker` is unable to open the Unix socket, `/var/run/docker.sock`.  Take a look at the permissions on that socket.  They may allow only root access:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-------. 1 root root 0 Sep  1 15:08 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Or they may allow access to a particular group:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw----. 1 root dockerroot 0 Sep  1 15:08 /var/run/docker.sock
```

In either case, the `go` user inside your container does not have access to this socket.  Ideally, you need to:

- (a) make the socket group-writable on the *host*
- (b) ensure that the `go` user in your container is a member of group with a gid that matches the gid on the *host*

Alternately, just run everything in your container as root, which avoids this particular problem but potentially exposes security issues if you are running untrusted code inside your containers.

Comment: Hi Iarsks, thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate on how I would accomplish (b) ? Also, re: running everything as root.. The GoCD agent seems to want to set it's 'go' user as part of the install. When I do a build, it then tries to use the 'go' agent. Truly appreciate your help.

Comment: in the container > add a group with a particular gid and ensure the go user is a member of it,

Comment: AKA this to **Add user 'go' to group docker to give permission to call docker-command**:

`usermod -a -G docker go`

Comment: Followed by this to **Make sure the group docker is associated with docker.sock**

`chgrp docker /var/run/docker.sock`